# Gradle project refresh failed. finished with non-zero exit value 2 with android studio 2.3 on linux bean

Tags: android, linux, gradle

I tried to develop android app with android studio.
But failed with gradle error.

Gradle project refresh failed [Error:Process 'command '/home/user/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2]

environment is below

- android studio2.3
- linux bean Linux version 3.13.0-101-generic (buildd@lgw01-05) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) #148-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 22:09:17 UTC 2016
- getconf LONG_BIT 32
- installed jdk jdk-8u111-linux-i586.tar.gz
- java version "1.8.0_111"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Is there any way to investigate the reason of the problem?

thanks!

---

Below is build.gradle.
This pjoject is just a sample, so I think build.gradle is not the reason.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: put your build.gradle here